# Update NULL values based on their neighbours

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `MyModel` that looks like this:

```
ID | Creation
---|-----------
 1 | 2017-01-01
 2 | NULL
 3 | NULL
 4 | 2017-01-09
 5 | NULL
```

And so forth.

I need to give a value to `Creation` where it is `NULL`, but...

**The `Creation` of each row needs to be greater than its predecessor.**

So the following query does not work for me

```
update MyModel
set Creation = getdate()
where Creation is null
```

Because it would break the rule.

The result ought to be something like

```
ID | Creation
---|-----------
 1 | 2017-01-01
 2 | 2017-01-02
 3 | 2017-01-03
 4 | 2017-01-09
 5 | 2017-01-10
```

---

> What if there are not enough days to have unique dates between two values?

Giving that the `Creation` is `datetime`, there will always be a valid `datetime` to be inserted. The difference between records is always greater than ~30 seconds.

> What if the existing values are not in order?

They are already in order. The order is based in their `ID`.

Comment: Can't you add a default value to this column to avoid this problem?

Comment: Not sure how you will deal with overlaps but you could use LEAD/LAG for this pretty easily. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql

Comment: @dirceusemighini I will create a constraint for this, but I already have a pretty big table with these gaps. Legacy code...

Comment: There are too many unknowns for this problem.  What if there are not enough days to have unique dates between two values?  What if the existing values are not in order?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please see my edit.

Comment: RE Space for Unique Dates: Since it's a datetime, you can go pretty granular in adding an additional date. That doesn't mean you'll "always" have a date to insert, but your range can be pretty broad. But you will get into precision issues if you have to go all the way down to thousandths of a second to insert a date. Speaking of, do you have any dates that come in at 1/1/2017 23:59:59.999, or something like that? Or do you have any CreationDates that are within 3 ms of each other with a NULL between? What date part do you want to add to keep these unique? Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Shawn Based on the data I have, there will always be a valid datetime to be inserted. My clarification is based on the data I have. I am sorry if it wasn't clear. I am working on SQL Server 14.0 (2017).

Comment: The difference between two `Creation`s are never less than 40 or 30 seconds, so we will not hit precision issues here. I will add it to the question.

Comment: Gotcha. My question wasn't so much about valid datetime. It was more about hitting a precision boundary. 1/1/2017 23:59:59.999 is a valid date time, but there are situations where it will look like 1/2/2017 00:00:00.000.

Comment: And to clarify, ID x Created date will always be less than ID x+1 Created date? I'm assuming there's some sort of business logic that prevents ID 10 from being 1/10 and ID 11 from being 1/3. Correct?

Comment: @Shawn Yes, `ID` is sorted just like `Creation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way if the gaps do not exceed the difference in days from the start and end of the gap.

```
declare @table table (ID int, Creation datetime)
insert into @table
values
(1,'2017-01-01'),
(2,NULL),
(3,NULL),
(4,'2017-01-09'),
(5,null),
(6,'2017-01-11'),
(7,null)

update t
set t.Creation = isnull(dateadd(day,(t2.id - t.ID) * -1,t2.creation),getdate())
from @table t
left join @table t2 on t2.ID > t.ID and t2.Creation is not null
where t.Creation is  null

select * from @table
```

**RETURNS**

```
+----+-------------------------+
| ID |        Creation         |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
|  2 | 2017-01-07 00:00:00.000 |
|  3 | 2017-01-08 00:00:00.000 |
|  4 | 2017-01-09 00:00:00.000 |
|  5 | 2017-01-10 00:00:00.000 |
|  6 | 2017-01-11 00:00:00.000 |
|  7 | 2017-10-25 11:58:56.353 |
+----+-------------------------+
```

Comment: If the last date is NULL, then the Creation Date may not be appropriate. Since it will be the only NULL date at the end, it might be better to fill that final date based on some other criteria. Or rather than getDate(), you could use a CTE to grab the last date and add 1+ day to that CTE date, then use that value in the isNULL().

Comment: Sometimes they do exceed the difference in days. The precision must be in minutes or even seconds.

Comment: @Gabriel then you can use minute instead of day for the dateaddfinction

Answer (score 1):

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (order by id)
  from mymodel
)
update cte
  set Creation = dateadd(day,cte.rn-x.rn,x.Creation)
from cte 
  cross apply (
    select top 1 *
    from cte i
    where i.creation is not null
      and i.id < cte.id
    order by i.id desc
    ) x
where cte.creation is null;

select * 
from mymodel;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WAA44339

returns:

```
+----+------------+
| id |  Creation  |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2017-01-01 |
|  2 | 2017-01-02 |
|  3 | 2017-01-03 |
|  4 | 2017-01-09 |
|  5 | 2017-01-10 |
+----+------------+
```